# phpMyAdmin login information?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to view my database by using phpMyAdmin. I was wondering where I can find out the server name that should be inputted into the form? I believe my username and password should be what I use when I access MySQL from the command line. Thanks[image]

**UPDATE:** Tried local host and 127.0.0.1 and got this error:
[image]

Comment: try `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`

Comment: Just edited my question with more information

Comment: Try no password. Just root and leave the password field blank.

Answer (score 0):

If you still can connect using the CLI mysql on the server console you can use the command below to see which account and host name you are able to use:

```
select * from mysql.user;
```

Eventually you can define a new sysadmin with password to be used with php as described at

https://corpocrat.com/2008/09/28/how-to-create-new-user-for-phpmyadmin-login/